# D3 chart doesn't show up

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to build a line and area chart based on the d3 example (http://bl.ocks.org/rkirsling/33a9e350516da54a5d4f). I copied and pasted the code and saved them in the right format. However, when I tried to view it via either a local file or localhost, the chart doesn't show up. The page is completely blank.

There are no console errors and the HTML page can connect to the javascript.

Also, I checked some previous similar questions and add the Jquery code: 
However, the page is still blank.
Can somebody tell me what is wrong? What should I do to make it show up in my page?

Comment: Have you checked the network console? I assume some files could not be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Things that can be fixed.

- change in app.css

  > @import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700);

  to

  > @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700);
- make sure that you have right file/dir structure.

  > /index.html
  >
  > /app.js
  >
  > /app.css
  >
  > /data.json
  >
  > /markers.json
- You need some server/localhost to load your `data.json` and `markers.json` files data in `app.js` code.

Comment: I have tried all three ways. Also, I am using the "python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000" to view the page. But this time, the page shows "Error response

Error code 404.

Message: File not found.

Error code explanation: 404 = Nothing matches the given URI."

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "you need some server/localhost" to load the json files?